# What is $\exp(-3|x|)$ mean?

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

In $\exp(-3|x|)$

While splitting the integral $x$ from $-\infty$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$, the first integral is replaced by $\exp(3x)$ and the second integral by $\exp(-3x)$?

I would like to know how do we obtain the first integral as $\exp(3x)$? The point I am confusing is mod means absolute(or positive value)? and then how comes the negative $x$ values remains negative?

Comment: $|x| = x$ when $x \geq 0$, and $|x| = -x$ when $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bungo! Are mod and abs  different? If so, What is the difference in symbols?

Comment: $|x|$ denotes the absolute value (or norm, or magnitude, or modulus) of $x$. I haven't heard the word "mod" used in this context, but if it is shorthand for "modulus" then the answer is yes, they mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @ Bungo. Absolute value is never negative. How do we relate this fact here?

Comment: Note that if $x \leq 0$, then $-x$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Oh!Now I got it! Thank you @Bungo

Comment: see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(%E2%88%923%7Cx%7C) for the graph

Answer (score 2):

$$
\exp(-3|x|)=\exp(-3x),x\geq0,\exp(3x),x<0
$$

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to understand $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ is that you always need negative powers of exponential function. So for $x<0$ you take $f(x)=e^x$ and for $x>0$ you take $f(x)=e^{-x}$.